# MySQL CONCAT 2 rows into 1 row with trailing \ sometimes

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to `CONCAT` 2 rows into 1 row in a different table.  The issue is that the `CONCAT` is on a Directory and a file path that sometimes has trailing '\'.  I was wondering what is the fastest way to do this with `MySQL`.

```
INSERT INTO [database.tableName] (full_path) SELECT CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, '\', A.File_Path) FROM [database.tableName2] as A where ID > 0;
```

Currently this gives me the correct answer some of the time. The issue is when the `Loc_Path` has a trailing `\`.

Example:

```
Loc_Path      |    File_Path
c:\test       |    yay.txt
c:\test\      |    yay.txt
```

This results are:

```
c:\test\yay.txt     [GOOD]
c:\test\\yay.txt    [BAD]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement to see if `Loc_Path` ends in a `\`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Loc_Path LIKE '%\\' 
            THEN CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, A.File_Path)
            ELSE CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, '\\', A.File_Path)
            END AS Result
FROM tableName2
WHERE ID > 0
```

Or using `SUBSTRING` rather than `LIKE`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN substring(Loc_Path , (char_length(Loc_Path ) - 1)) = '\\' 
            THEN CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, A.File_Path)
            ELSE CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, '\\', A.File_Path)
            END AS Result
FROM tableName2
WHERE ID > 0
```

Don't forget to [escape your backslash](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html).